# How to set to use DPAPI or not?

Tags: winapi, cryptoapi, dpapi

I learn about WIN API methods responsible for secure storage. I read about CryptoAPI and DPAPI:

> "The public DPAPI interfaces are part of Crypt32.dll and are available
>   for any user process that has loaded it. This DLL is part of
>   CryptoAPI."

So when I want to use `CryptProtectData` I call `CryptProtectData` from `Crypt32.dll`. But when I want to use DPAPI I must call `CryptProtectData` from `Crypt32.dll` too. How can I set to use DPAPI or not,  to use CryptoAPI or not?

EDIT: How can I know what I do not use DPAPI? And how can I "say" a program to use DPAPI?

Comment: " *But when I want to use DPAPI I must call CryptProtectData from Crypt32.dll too* " Yes .. can you explain why this is a problem?

Comment: When I use CryptoAPI without DPAPI? How can I know what I do not use DPAPI? And how can I "say" a program to use DPAPI?

Comment: If you call either of the two DPAPI functions in Crypt32.dll then your using the DPAPI, if you call other functions your using the CryptoAPI

Comment: I cannot call CryptProtectData what will not use DPAPI. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: CryptProtectData is one of the functions labelled as being part of the "DPAPI", there is only one implementation of it